# Import Comma Delimited Unicode Text file to PHP

Tags: php, csv, unicode, explode

Text Sample in mytxt.txt

```
Budu Bawa Pathana,බුදු බව පතනා,budu-bawa-pathana 
Budu Piya Mage,බුදු පියා මගේ,budu-piya-mage
Dewathi Deva Raja,දෙවැති දේව රාජා,dewathi-deva-raja 
Domnase Mulawe,දොම්නසේ මුලාවේ,domnase-mulawe
```

Script :

```
$lines = file('mytxt.txt');
$count = count($lines);

// Two dimensional array
$datax = array();

$i = 0;

foreach($lines as $value) {

    if($i!=0):
        list($id,$english,$sinhala,$html) = explode(",", $value);
        $datax[$i]['id'] = $id;
        $datax[$i]['eng'] = $english;
        $datax[$i]['sin'] =$sinhala;
        $datax[$i]['html'] = $html;
    endif;
    $i++;
}
$data['impData'] = $datax;
```

When I'm running the script. The Sinhala Unicode text are showing like Black boxes. 
Is there any solution for me to print the results as Unicode text ?
HTML headers are set to utf-8

Comment: Use fgetcsv() to read a csv file, and make sure the file was opened with the "b" mode flag

Comment: Does text look correct if you do `include('mytxt.txt');`?

Comment: Yes It does, Showing the text correctly

Comment: are you doing anything else to the data

Comment: I used fgetcsv($file,1000',',','b'). i can see the unicode now. but the array is stopping after the 2nd row.